# How to fetch email address from MFMailComposer's recipients address

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, email, mfmailcomposer

I wants to fetch email address from the recipients address in MFMailComposer after the user enters the recipients address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to get Recipient email addresses. Please go through the below link which will help you to get email addresses..

http://jomnius.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-find-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller.html

also if you have any idea of how to get From email address. pls do let me know.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are no ways to get the components(information) of MFMailComposeViewController once it has been opened/launched.

Comment: If I implement this in my application,whether App Store will reject it  ?

Comment: If you have some related link to this.please provide me.